# PHP Exec not working but the command itself is working fine

Tags: php, mysql, sybase

I tried to insert some data to 2 separate db platforms, first one is mySql and the other one is SQLAnywhere 11. For mysql i used the php `mysql_query` method to insert the database, and for SQLAnywhere 11 i'm using the `dbisql` command with php `exec()` function. The command itself is working properly in the `cmd.exe` but when i tried it with php it's not working.

Here's the trial code :

```
   <?php 

    $cid = rand(0, 100);

    $first_name = "Test";

    $last_name = "Test 2";



    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    if ($connect) {

        mysql_select_db("db_person");

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_person (cid, first_name, last_name) VALUES ($cid, '$first_name', '$last_name')") or die(mysql_error());

        $query2 = "INSERT INTO table_person (cid, first_name, last_name) VALUES ($cid, '$first_name', '$last_name')";

        $cmd = 'C:/"Program Files"/"SQL Anywhere 11"/Bin32/dbisql.exe -d1 '.strtolower($query2).' -c "UID=dba;PWD=axia1234;DSN=Payroll11"';

        $output = NULL;



        $exec = exec($cmd, $output);

        var_dump($output);

    } else {

        echo "Fail";

    }

?>
```

Been trying to run this script some couple times and it always works.

Example:

```
C:/"Program Files"/"SQL Anywhere 11"/Bin32/dbisql.exe -d1 insert into table_person (cid, first_name, last_name) values (70, 'test', 'test 2') -c "UID=dba;PWD=axia1234;DSN=Payroll11"
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is probably  because the arguments you are passing to the command is unescaped

Comment: Using mysql_* functions are not suggested as they are depricated in PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use mysqli_* functions instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Hi @SumanBanerjee, the problem is on the exec() function, not in the mysql_* function. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @DominickNavarro, as you can see i'm using a single string quotes on the command. So it is fine to use a single backslash. Or maybe you can give an example of how should i do to my command, if it's working maybe you can type in as an answer and i'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What's the meaning of "it's not working"?
Does it do an empty record or nothing?

According the [exec quickref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

you can pass pointers in to get the output and status of the command.

```
 $exec = exec($cmd, $output, $pointer);
 if(!pointer){
   echo "success exec\n"; 
 }
 else{
 echo "failed exec \n";     
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Pythagoras , Thank you for your input. It does nothing. As you can see i'm trying to insert 1 data to the SQLAnywhere database, i've extracted the returning string of the query from the .php file and copy it to the cmd.exe and it running well and inserting as i expected. The thing is, the exec() command did nothing when i try to run it.

Comment: @sunstation You can get more info about the error with the following syntax: exec('some_command 2>&1', $output);  print_r($output). It will show you what's not going on.

Comment: Yes, the error is about odbc connection, it seems like it couldn't connected to the odbc, but the command works perfectly in the cmd.exe!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concatinating your query directly to the command the output will be like this:

`C:/"Program Files"/"SQL Anywhere 11"/Bin32/dbisql.exe -d1 insert into table_person (cid, first_name, last_name) values (70, 'test', 'test 2') -c "UID=dba;PWD=axia1234;DSN=Payroll11"`

on command prompt this will be an error because:

`insert into table_person (cid, first_name, last_name) values (70, 'test', 'test 2')`

have spaces and special characters

try using `"insert into table_person (cid, first_name, last_name) values (70, 'test', 'test 2')"`

so your command will be:

`$cmd = 'C:/"Program Files"/"SQL Anywhere 11"/Bin32/dbisql.exe -d1 "'.strtolower($query2).'" -c "UID=dba;PWD=axia1234;DSN=Payroll11"';`